# How to dynamically change Django Form field type (e.g. `forms.CharField` to `forms.ChoiceField`) without changing the data member variable?

Tags: javascript, django, forms, dynamic, widget

**TL;DR**

How can I change the search term CharField (of any of the rows in the image below) to another field type (e.g. ChoiceField, DateField, etc) based on the type of the selected database field (in the first select list on that row - see screenshot below)?

**Long version**

I have a cool hierarchical advanced search interface, e.g.:

[image]

Each row specifies a search term/condition and reads as a search, like:

`<field>` `<condition>` `<term>`

e.g.

`age` `>` `5`

where the form field names are:

- `fld` (for "database field")
- `ncmp` (for "negatable comparison type")
- `val` (for the search term)

*There is a hidden field called `pos` for the hierarchy and group type data, but that's irrelevant to my question.*

Rows and subgroups can be dynamically added/removed to/from the hierarchy and can be `and-ed` or `or-ed` together.

It works great.  But the problem I want to solve is that it is somewhat limited by field type.  I would like to be able to dynamically change the contents of the `condition` select list (`ncmp`) and the type of search term field (`val`) based on the selected database field (`fld`) (or the selected `condition`, e.g. if `isnull`: hide the term field).  Here are some examples of what I want:

1. If the selected `field` is a timestamp, I'd like the `condition` list to have selections like `before/after/on day/etc` and the `term` field to be a "timestamp" field with like a calendar widget or something
2. If the `field` is a number type DB field, remove the `contains/ends with/starts with/etc` `condition` items and use a number validator on the `term` field
3. If the `field` is an enumeration DB field, populate the `condition` select list with `is/is not/is null/is not null/etc` and make the `term` field a select list

Are there any standard ways to do this?  Ideally, the form would still only have the 3 fields (`fld`, `ncmp`, and `val`) so that I wouldn't have to overhaul the hierarchy javascript that controls the formsets, but I can do that if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a completely comprehensive answer to this yet, but I have implemented ways to:

1. update the `ncmp` select list based on the selected value in the `fld` select list.
2. change the `val` form field type between a text field (for number/string database fields), a select list (for enumerated/"choices" database fields), and hidden (when `ncmp` is something like "is null" or "is not null").

I haven't figured out a way to use different Django widgets and accomplished the above using javascript.  There are a few things to keep in mind:

- The Django form class must define the `ncmp` field with all possible values regardless of which `fld` is currently selected and the javascript simply repopulates the select list on the subset corresponding to the current `fld` selection.
- For the `val` field, I changed the Django form class's `val` field to be a hidden field, and render a number of initially hidden form fields in javascript on each row, which I hide/show based on the current `fld` and `ncmp` value.  Every javascript copy of the `val` field updates the value of the always hidden `val` field.

I imagine that any other representation of the `val` field would have to also be done in javascript and must be able to update a single hidden `val` field.  So if you had multiple javascript-generated fields to enter the `val` (e.g. 3 text entries for a phone number or social security number), the javascript would have to condense that into a single string to update the hidden `val` field.